# Looking for solution to manually control automated selenium driver on linux server

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So, I have multiple selenium chrome drivers doing automated tasks with python on multiple linux servers. 99% of the tasks is automated until it runs into situations that require human involvement.

I am currently using VNC to connect to my linux server and control the chrome but I am not enjoying at all.

I am simply trying to find a better solution.

Thanks!

EDIT:

To be more specific, since the chrome drives sometimes need to be controlled by other people and I actually don't want third-party to connect to my server with VNC.

I have actually tried to re-direct the whole browsing session to local PC when human control is needed (like what proxy servers do) but I didn't succeed.

Comment: You don't like VNC or you don't want to connect to server? Doesn't manually mean "connect to host and do something"?

Comment: can you pls explain little bit more about it!!